# htdocs not a working copy SVN cleanup

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I try and checkout any folder from the repository I get an error:

> Previous operation has not finished, run 'cleanup' if it was interrupted.

When I attempt this on any folder anywhere, including `htdocs` in `xampp` I get the same error:

> Cleanup failed to process the following paths:
>   c:\xampp\htdocs
>   c:\xampp\htdocs is not a working copy

I'm only learning SVN but it seems I've lost my entire SVN up set or something (my folders don't have green ticks anymore).

Does anyone have any advice for a beginner? I had been using it fine for a few weeks.

Comment: Has anything relevant changed since your last successful svn operation? Did you update TortoiseSVN? Advice: Check your svn backups. 8-I

Comment: Well to be honest it started when I got an error when trying to do `sudo svn update` and was getting errors about unversioned files of the same name. So on windows I started taking out folders and moving them and committing again. 

Sorry for stupid question but how do I check SVN backups, if I could go back a few days I wouldnt be bothered about losing data etc

Comment: Sorry, the comment about the backups was somewhat sarcastic and it postulates that YOU made a backup of your repositories.

Comment: oh right lol, no unfortunately. Overall Im not sure how to proceed,, my repositories are fine, its bringing them local thats the issue, Im wondering is it worth uninstalling Tortoise SVN and just starting again

Comment: What about creating a new repository from your working copy? I hope you have a healthy working copy!? In this case the change history is lost, but you wrote that you are using it just for a few weeks, so what ...

Comment: This issue isnt just specific to one repository, it seems when even with a new repository when I try and checkout to local, I get the same errors